# Extract complex json with random key field

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I am trying to extract the following JSON into its own rows like the table below in Presto query. The issue here is the name of the key/av engine name is different for each row, and I am stuck on how I can extract and iterate on the keys without knowing the value of the key.

The json is a value of a table row

```
{
    "Bkav":
    {
        "detected": false,
        "result": null,
    },
    "Lionic":
    {
        "detected": true,
        "result": Trojan.Generic.3611249',
    },
    ...
```

| AV Engine Name | Detected Virus | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bkav | false | null |
| Lionic | true | Trojan.Generic.3611249 |

I have tried to use json_extract following the documentation here https://teradata.github.io/presto/docs/141t/functions/json.html but there is no mention of extraction if we don't know the key :( I am trying to find a solution that works in both presto & hive query, is there a common query that is applicable to both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast your json to `map(varchar, json)` and process it with `unnest` to flatten:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset (json_str) AS (
    VALUES (
            '{"Bkav":{"detected": false,"result": null},"Lionic":{"detected": true,"result": "Trojan.Generic.3611249"}}'
        )
) 

--query
select k "AV Engine Name", json_extract_scalar(v, '$.detected') "Detected Virus", json_extract_scalar(v, '$.result') "Result"
from (
        select cast(json_parse(json_str) as map(varchar, json)) as m
        from dataset
    )
cross join unnest (map_keys(m), map_values(m)) t(k, v)
```

Output:

| AV Engine Name | Detected Virus | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bkav | false |  |
| Lionic | true | Trojan.Generic.3611249 |

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work in Presto, but not in Hive, as it can't recognize the map, wondering if you know what the work around for it is?

Comment: @Ohhh sorry, do not know.

Answer (score 1):

The presto query suggested by @Guru works, but for hive, there is no easy way.

1. I had to extract the json
2. Parse it with replace to remove some character and bracket
3. Then convert it back to a map, and repeat for one more time to get the nested value out

```
SELECT
    av_engine,
    str_to_map(regexp_replace(engine_result, '\\}', ''),',', ':') AS output_map
FROM (
    SELECT
        str_to_map(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(get_json_object(raw_response, '$.scans'), '\"', ''), '\\{',''),'\\},', ':') AS key_val_map
    FROM restricted_antispam.abuse_malware_scanning
) AS S
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(key_val_map) temp AS av_engine, engine_result
```